# Separating an integer and adding the values with support for a negative integer

Tags: java

I have an assignment to break an integer into it's individual digits, report them back to the user, and add them. I can do that, but I'm struggling with supporting negative integers. Here's my code, which works exactly the way I want it to, but only for positive integers:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Module4e
{
   static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer:  ");
        String myNum=console.nextLine();  //Collects the number as a string
        int[] asNumber=new int[myNum.length()]; 
        String []upNum=new String[myNum.length()];  //updated
        int sum=0;  //sum starts at 0
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("The digits of the number are:  ");

        for (int i=0;i<myNum.length();i++)
        {
            upNum[i]=myNum.substring(i,i+1);
            System.out.print(upNum[i]);
            System.out.print(" ");
            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(upNum[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("The sum of the digits is: ");
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I've found plenty of hints for getting this to work with *positive* integers, but none for negatives.

Comment: Hint: think about how you'd negate an integer.

Comment: [`Math.abs(n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int))?  I can't imagine that the answer for a negative integer would be any different than that of its absolute value.

Comment: `boolean negative = myNum.startsWith("-"); if (negative) { myNum = myNum.substring(1); }`

Comment: Put an if statement in your loop that checks if the substring is a "-" and if it is, get the next substring before doing the add.

Comment: What is the input (e.g. -123-4-5)? And what do yout expected (e.g. -5 from the Digits before)?

Comment: @drkunibar, if the input is 12345, I would want it to return 1 2 3 4 5 and a sum of 15; there would only be a leading "-" for negatives, eg -12345, which should return -1 2 3 4 5 with a sum of 14.

Comment: -1 2 3 4 5 has the sum 13.

Comment: See my answer with the regulare expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegExp

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestDigits {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Validate Input
        String number = console.nextLine();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(-?[0-9]{1})+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(number);
        if (!m.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Numbers");
        }
        // Calculate
        p = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]{1}+");
        m = p.matcher(number);
        int result = 0;
        System.out.print("The digits of the number are:  ");
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
            result += Integer.valueOf(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Result " + result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  The last one worked as expected.  Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I think you can use this code //also you can multiply the number by -1
int positive = 0;
//positive give you information about the number introduced by the user
if (myNum.charAt(0)=='-'){
     positive=1;
}else{
    positive=0;
for (int i=positive; i<myNum.length(); i++){
    //be carefull with index out of bound exception
    if ((i+1)<myNum.length()){
        upNum[i]=myNum.substring(i,i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This one still gave me the absolute values, but there are some things in here that I'll definitely reference again later!

Answer (score 0):

Change the statement String myNum=console.nextLine() to String myNum = String.valueOf(Math.abs(Integer.valueOf(console.nextLine())));

Comment: This one performed the addition on the absolute values - but I have another program that this line will be useful for.  Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use String to solve this problem.  Here's my thought.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Module4e throws IllegalArgumentException {
    static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer:  ");
        if (!console.hasNextInt()) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
        int myNum=console.nextInt();
        myNum = Math.abs(myNum);
        int sum=0;
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("The digits of the number are:  ");
        While (myNum > 10) {
             System.out.print(myNum % 10);
             System.out.print(" ");
             sum += myNum % 10;
             myNum /= 10;
        }
        System.out.println(myNum);
        System.out.print("The sum of the digits is: ");
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying to use the % and / method initially and had trouble with it.  This was a useful reference!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I gave -51 as input and got -6 as output. This is what you are looking for?

```
import  java.util.*;
public class LoggingApp
{
   static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int multiple = 1;      
       System.out.print("Enter an integer:  ");
       String myNum=console.nextLine();  //Collects the number as a string
       Integer myNumInt = Integer.parseInt(myNum);
       if (myNumInt < 1){
           multiple = -1;
           myNum = Integer.toString(myNumInt*-1);
       }
       int[] asNumber=new int[myNum.length()]; 
       String []upNum=new String[myNum.length()];  //updated
       int sum=0;  //sum starts at 0
       System.out.println("\n");
       System.out.print("The digits of the number are:  ");
       for (int i=0;i<myNum.length();i++)
       {
           upNum[i]=myNum.substring(i,i+1);
           System.out.print(upNum[i]);
           System.out.print(" ");
           sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(upNum[i])*multiple;
       }
       System.out.println("\n");
       System.out.print("The sum of the digits is: ");
       System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: Close!  When I put in -12345, I got -15 instead of 13.  Thanks so much for your help, though!  I'm learning a little more from all of the programs posted.